# Reduce function that outputs multiple values

Tags: couchdb

I have a Couch datebase with multiple users, and I'd like to create a reduce function that outputs a number for each user.

Let's say this is my database:

```
{
   user: "A",
   event: "x",
   time: 100
}
{
   user: "A",
   event: "y",
   time: 150
}
{
   user: "B",
   event: "x",
   time: 300
}
{
   user: "B",
   event: "y",
   time: 375
}
```

I'd like to know the time between events x and y for each user. That is, I'd like an output something like

```
{
   user: "A",
   xyTime: 50
}
{
   user: "B",
   xyTime: 75
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your map function to be:

```
function(doc){
  emit(doc.user, {event:doc.event, time: doc.xyTime});
}
```

And in your reduce, you can iterate over all of the values:

```
function(keys,values){
  var xTime = 0
  var yTime = 0;
  var length = values.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    var eventTime = parseInt(values[i].time, 10);
    if(values[i].event === "x"){
      xTime += eventTime;
    } else {
      yTime += eventTime;
    }
  }
  var xyTime = Math.abs(xTime - yTime);

  return { user: keys[0], xyTime:  xyTime };
}
```